# Jquery alert printing outhtml tags

Tags: php, jquery, html

I have PHP code that creates a table with values from my DB. But when i try to Alert the table in JQuery it displays the html tags aswell as the correct values.

Can someone tell me how to stop the tags from being displayed.

Hers the code for the table

```
echo "<table border='1' width='150' cellpadding='0' cellspacing='0'>";
echo"<tr><th>Stats</th><th>name</th></tr>   ";
echo "<tr><td>var</td> <td>{$var} </td></tr>";
echo "<tr><td>var1</td> <td> {$var1} </td></tr>";
echo "<tr><td>var2</td> <td> {$var2}</td> </tr>";
echo "<tr><td>var3</td> <td>{$var3}  </td></tr>";
echo "<tr><td>var4 </td> <td>{$var4 }</td></tr>";
echo "<tr><td>var5</td> <td>{$var5} </td></tr>";
echo "<tr><td>var6</td> <td>{$var6} </td></tr>";
echo "</table>"
```

thanks, heres the jquery

```
 $('.but').live('click', function()
{
    $.post('display.php',function(output)
    {
        alert(output);
    });
});
```

THis is what is getting shown in the alert

```
<table border='1' width='150' cellpadding='0' cellspacing='0'><tr><th>Stats</th> 
<th>name</th></tr>  <tr><td>name</td> <td>0 </td></tr><tr><td>var1</td> <td> 2 </td> 
</tr><tr><td>var2</td> <td> 90</td> </tr><tr><td>var3 </td> <td>0  </td></tr><tr> 
 <td>var 4 </td> <td>2</td></tr><tr><td>var5</td> <td>0 </td></tr><tr><td>var6</td> 
 <td>0 </td></tr></table>
```

I want  table shown in the alert , not the above ,

Comment: Can you post your JavaScript code as well?

Comment: yea its just an on button click

Comment: sounds like you are trying to alert an ajax response and you will seee the html there, need to post your script

Comment: And what is the expected behavior?

Comment: I'm not sure if I understand correctly, but if you don't want the tags, then don't echo them in the script?

Comment: well a table with values in it, it works when  i dont use an alert,

Comment: need to clarify what it is you want... no unexpected behavior so far from what you've said and shown in code

Comment: Do you expect the table to magicly render inside the alert box ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

when you alert something it tries to covert the value toString thats why the output is not rendered as HTML table as it is in the browser. If you want to display the out put use some modal plugin like the [jquery UI modal](http://jqueryui.com/demos/dialog/#modal-form).

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/L9P22/3/)

Answer (score 1):

If you want to display html in an alert as text, you would need to parse the text out of each cell and format it into a text string using "\n" as line breaks.

A simpler solution would be to use one of the many alert plugins that allow use of either html or text with line breaks such as :

http://labs.abeautifulsite.net/archived/jquery-alerts/demo/

Or return formatted text from server if all you want is a broser default alert.